# connect 2 checkbuttons with a line in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter, canvas

I have a program to place checkbuttons in a canvas, when the option (another checkbutton) is selected. I have another option (another checkbutton) to draw a line. In order to draw the line, first I should select the checkbutton "draw a line", then clicked any checkbutton placed in the canvas, and another clicked anywhere on the canvas. This work with the first checkbutton i place, but if I place several checkbuttons, it only draw the line from the last checkbutton place in the canvas, and no from the checkpoint I select.
I believe I should create a dictionary to keep track of the checkbuttons I place so I can call them back, but I don't know how to implement that, any idea how to do it?

```
    from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top_canvas = Canvas(root,width=1376,height=768, bg='light blue')
top_canvas.pack()

buttons = []

class CMD:  #Auxilliary function for callbacks using parameters. Syntax: CMD(function, argument1, argument2, ...)
    def __init__(s1, func, *args):
        s1.func = func
        s1.args = args
    def __call__(s1, *args):
        args = s1.args+args
        s1.func(*args)

def color_checkbutton(pos):  # define the colors of the checkbutton
    checkbutton_available()
    if buttons[pos][0].get() == 1:
        buttons[pos][2].configure(bg='red')
    else:
        buttons[pos][2].configure(bg='green')

def place_checkbutton_in_canvas(e):  # order to insert the checkbutton
    if len(str(e.widget))<12: ## Don't place a new one if a checkbox was clicked
        b = IntVar()
        pos = len(buttons)
        global xx, yy
        xx = e.x
        yy = e.y
        buttons.append([b,pos, Checkbutton(top_canvas, variable=b, textvariable=b, command=CMD(color_checkbutton, pos))])
        buttons[-1][2].place(x=xx, y=yy)
        color_checkbutton(pos)

def place_checkbutton():  #to run when checkbutton is selected. Now the checkbutton will be placed where mouse clicked if choose_line is selected
    top_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', place_checkbutton_in_canvas)

def checkbutton_available():
    def drawline(ev):
        flx = ev.x
        fly = ev.y
        def auxiliary():
           lineor = top_canvas.create_line(xx, yy, flx, fly, width =3, fill = 'red')
        auxiliary()
    if chosen_option.get() == 2:
            top_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', drawline)

chosen_option = IntVar()
choose_checkbutton = Radiobutton(top_canvas, text = "place checkbutton", variable=chosen_option, value = 1, command = place_checkbutton)
choose_checkbutton.place(x=10, y=10)
choose_line = Radiobutton(top_canvas, text = "draw line", variable=chosen_option, value = 2)
choose_line.place(x=10, y=100)

top_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', place_checkbutton_in_canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you draw a line from (xx, yy) to (flx, fly), but your coordinates (xx, yy) seems to be a global var only defined in the place_checkbutton_in_canvas(e) function.

So (xx, yy) contain the coordinates of the last checkbox you placed. And the start point of your line is ony only redefined when you place a new checkbutton.

To correct this you should assign the (xx, yy) global var when a checkbox is selected.

Also if you want to draw lines from multiples start points, only two int variables (xx and yy) is not sufficient. You need to have two arrays of ints (or an array of pairs) to store the positions of all currenlty checked values.

If instead you doesn't want multiple line draw at the same time, maybe you should use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: I want to draw lines from multiples start points, and I understand I need to use a dictionary or arrays, but I don't know how to implement it. everytime i place a checkbutton, a new entry should go into the dictionary. What i don't see is how I can create a new key with the value of the variable pos (what I use to give the checkbutton a number)

Comment: I'm not realy sure why you want a dictionnary. My first approch would be to make an array, and each time you add a checkbox put it coordinate in it. You end up with some thing like that [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), ...] where it may become harder is if later you want to remove them because the position in the array may change.

Comment: A more advanced solution, would be no to store your checkbox coordinates and add/remove them according to the checkbox state, but just store a pointer to all your checkboxes objectdirectly. Indeed, as your checkbox objects already store their own position themselves, you can get that information easily. In addition you can at the same time verify if your checkbox is ticked or not.